# Remove last number from lines

Tags: python

I have file1

```
AX A1,A2 ZN 3
BP A1,A2,B Z 2
CLK I Z 1
```

I want to remove the last number from each line giving fout as

```
AX A1,A2 ZN 
BP A1,A2,B Z 
CLK I Z
```

I tried using `sep` but getting only first or second words or third word before sep.

```
sep =' '
l= line.split(sep, 3)[0]
```

Is there any other way I can remove last digit from each line.

Comment: You don't need to select a separator, use `rsplit(1)[0]` and you'll have what you want

Comment: What should happen if the line doesn't end with a number?

Comment: @anishtain4 did you mean `rsplit(' ', 1)[0]`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Good point, I forgot to determine/skip the separator. You're right.

Answer (score 3):

You can can take all but the last element, so like this:

```
l = line.split(sep)[:-1]
```

Does this solve your problem? [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is the documentation of the split function. That might help as well.

Comment: Did you mean `sep.join(line.split(sep)[:-1])`? Currently `l` is a list...

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah, your result is better as it is a string again. I didn't write that, because I thought it is sufficient enough to just show a way to remove the last element from a line.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more efficient way than using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is using [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition). More specifically, [`rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition). This splits the string ***from the right*** (once) returning a tuple of the form `(left, sep, right)`. So in your case:

```
l = line.rpartition(' ')[0]
```

Comment: Using above code. I am getting only 1st two lines printed. I am not getting the last line printed.@Tomerikoo

Comment: I used the modified code edited in the question can you please check.   but getting only 1st and second line printed. Not getting the last line.@Tomerikoo

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY can you be more specific? I get the correct output for the given data... It sounds like the problem is with your loop rather than with this specific line...